# C++ Помогите решить проблему

Tags: c++

Задача
Шахматная ладья ходит по горизонтали или вертикали. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли ладья попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом.

Формат входных данных
Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки.
Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести YES, если из первой клетки ходом ладьи можно попасть во вторую или NO в противном случае.
Решение

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
    if (x1 = x2 || y1 = y2) {
        cout << 'YES';
    }
    else {
        cout << 'NO';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка
C++ выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Comment: Указывайте строку с ошибкой. У вас используется оператор присваивания вместо оператора сравнения в условии. У вас неверное условие решения задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы решал проще:

```
cout << ((x1-x2)*(y1-y2) ? "NO" : "YES");
```

Ваша же ошибка - паскалевская - это там проверка на равенство `=`. Здесь надо писать

```
if (x1 == x2 || y1 == y2) { ...
```